# How to print std::numeric_limits<double>::signaling_NaN() without FE_INVALID being set

Tags: c++, nan

I find it useful to check `fetestexcept(FE_INVALID)`. However, just printing the value `std::numeric_limits<double>::signaling_NaN()` (e.g., with `std::cout`) seems to set this flag, whereas I only want the flag to be set if the `NaN` is used in a floating point operation. Is it possible to print without changing `FE_INVALID` flag?

Comment: Are you literally printing `std::numeric_limits<double>::signaling_NaN()` or are you printing some (run-time computed) object whose value is a signaling NaN? Why not just print a string that represents a signaling NaN? How about clearing `FE_INVALID` after printing?

Comment: It happens when I print `std::numeric_limits<double>::signaling_NaN()` directly, and of course also an object whose value is a signaling NaN.

Comment: I asked because the solutions may differ, not because I want to know how printing behaves in one situation or another. The point is to get at the actual problem you are trying to solve. Normally, signaling NaNs do not arise in computation. Objects are initialized with signaling NaNs so that, if they are used inadvertently, an exception is raised, typically indicating the program has a bug. Getting to the point where a program is printing signaling NaNs as a “normal” operation is weird, and not wanting the invalid flag raised by that is also weird. The situation should be explained.

Comment: For missing values in arrays, I populate the initial state as `std::numeric_limits<double>::signaling_NaN()`. I never want to use these values in a calculation, but I sometimes print the entire array. So that's why I want to be able to print the values without setting FE_INVALID.

Comment: A C++ implementation that raises invalid when printing a signaling NaN is probably not going to give you some means to turn that off. The C++ standard does not require it. You should probably either initialize with quiet NaNs or, while printing, test for a NaN (with `isnan`) and print “nan” or “NAN” instead.

Comment: Probably. It's hard to test for NaN as I compile with `-ffast-math`, so `std::isnan` always returns false. I could probably test for the raw bit pattern, or, perhaps better, condition on another boolean variable. It would be simpler to just print the signalling NaN without setting `FE_INVALID`, but perhaps that's not possible. I could also clear `FE_INVALID` as you suggest, although I'm not sure if there's a latency penalty that is material relative to the latency penalty of doing any printing.

Comment: Re “It's hard to test for NaN as I compile with -ffast-math, so std::isnan always returns false”: Put the routine that prints the array in a separate source file that is compiled without `-ffast-mmath`.